# MySQL - archiving data in tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am a developer for an insurance app. We are using AWS RDS with a MySQL implementation. The scenario we would want is to automatically archive data from one table to another. Something like this:

Let's say you have a table called user_profile. You want to record a history of the changes of each user profile in another table, let's say we call it user_profile_history. Is it possible in RDS to do real time porting from the main user_profile table to its history table, whenever updates are done to the main table?

End scenario would be, user_profile table only contain the latest user data. All other past snapshots of profile are in the history table.

I did my due diligence and did a little bit of research and there are possible options to do this:

1. MySql Event scheduler
2. Cron Job
3. Partitioning

My question is, which do you think would be best suited specifically for this scenario? or are there other better ones that I have missed? Currently records in the main table are in the millions (15M approximately) with about 5k records added each day. That is why we decided to have a separate history/archive table to it, to be able to transfer some of the old stale data to a separate table.

Comment: _ones that I have missed?_ Triggers, perhaps?

Comment: @mustacio Ok we can add that option but which do you think would be the best option?

Comment: Please consider posting TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE user_profile;  and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'user_profile';  for analysis.  We may see some data that might permit getting you to less than 15M rows in this important table.

Answer (score 1):

I think triggers is your best option as mustaccio mentioned.
There are multiple options:

Create a BEFORE INSERT Trigger
Create an AFTER INSERT Trigger
Create a BEFORE UPDATE Trigger
Create an AFTER UPDATE Trigger
Create a BEFORE DELETE Trigger
Create an AFTER DELETE Trigger

Select the one you want, or all :D, you can control it all.

See also this tutorial:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it when initially storing the data.  Two tables:

`History` contains all the data, including what was just now received.  Example: all your bank statements on a single list.

`Current` contains the information as of now.  Example: your current balance.

The `History` contains all the data necessary to reconstruct what is in `Current`.